# Why used axios in vue.js with typescript error “ element implicitly has type 'any' because axios element has no index signature

Tags: typescript, vue.js, axios

I try to encapsulation axios in global file, but when i import axios in my file , then i create a variable for request .but has error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should define type `string` to `requestName`

```js
let requestName: string = config.data.requestName
```

Object key type is always string. The linter just warns you that `any` type can have potential error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer，but it not workink . I hava no idea to fix this problem now , so , i give up using this  。 thank you again ;